# I am sharing my iMac's ethernet connection as a WiFi hotspot. Who is connected?

Tags: macos, wifi, internet-sharing

I would like to monitor who connects to my iMac's WiFi hotspot.  I have protected it with a password, but WEP is easy to crack. Is there a utility for OS 10.7.3/Lion to see who is connected?

Comment: Everyone should be aware of who is using his network, and that WEP is just… **false** security.

Comment: @danielAzuelos At least in 2012, Apple didn’t offer anything better than WEP in OS X. Some systems, e.g. first Intel-powered Macs (32bit), are limited to 10.6 or lower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arp -a`

gives a list of connected interfaces on the same network.

- `en1` is Wi-Fi
- `en0` is Ethernet (on the Macbook Air this is Wi-Fi)

#### How to use

Type this command in the Terminal located at `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`. To learn more about this command, type `man arp` in the terminal.

Comment: In hindsight, this is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a network map like [Nmap](http://nmap.org/) to 'map out' your connection, and see who is connected. Alternatively, [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) should let you see what they do (ie what they visit).

Comment: But does Little Snitch also show who's connected?

Comment: I've actually never tried. I wouldn't imagine so though - just the data flow in and out.

Comment: I use little snitch. When someone first connected, it gave me one prompt. After that, there is nothing showing a list of clients. Further, there are legitimate clients whose traffic I don't want to monitor. I simply want to know if additional clients are associated. I'll check out nmap too, but as you noted on the other answer, arp works well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a command I let in an `xterm` (or `Terminal`) running to be aware of neighbour
attempting to enter my WEP **unprotected** Wi-Fi network:

```
/usr/bin/sudo tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep 'bootpd.*\[en.\]'
```

When this window starts to scroll, I know I got a new uninvited guest at
home.

If I want to know afterward who attempted to access my network, I can find it with:

```
/usr/bin/sudo grep 'bootpd.*\[en.\]' /var/log/system.log
```

Comment: The Apple way would probably to keep a Console.app window open. Note that there’s Filter <kbd>⌥⌘F</kbd> and Find <kbd>⌘F</kbd> available, but no regular expressions.